# instalar npm pero tengo warn

Tags: npm

Hola tengo ese tipo de error a la hora de probar npm, aunque me muestra la ultima versión que tengo. alguien podría indicarme que me pide la consola? y como solucionarlo porfavor. gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, `npm install` (el comando que has introducido) busca un archivo llamado `package.json`, que incluye las dependencias del programa. Parece ser que estás ejecutando `npm install` en un directorio que no tiene ese archivo, así que te está dando error.

Comment: Te falta el archivo `package.json`, no existe en el directorio.

Comment: hola! desinstale nodejs, ya que estaba cargado incompleto. reinstalé y quedo bárbaro. muchas gracias a todos.